# sqoop imports a lot of NULL rows

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm importing a table from mysql to hive. The table has `2115584` rows. During the import I see

```
13/03/20 18:34:31 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 2115584 records.
```

But when I do a `count(*)` on the imported table I see that it has `49262250` rows. What is going on?

Update: the import works correctly when `--direct` is specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. From the sqoop user manual:

> Hive will have problems using Sqoop-imported data if your database’s rows contain string fields that have Hive’s default row delimiters (\n and \r characters) or column delimiters      (\01 characters) present in them. You can use the --hive-drop-import-delims option to drop  those characters on import to give Hive-compatible text data.

I just specified `--hive-drop-import-delims` and it works now.